# How to take value from a variable and store them in different variables

Tags: c, dev-c++

Ok so my question is that if a variable for e.g lets say num = 1562 (num is an integer variable) and I want to take 1 and store it into a different variable and take 5 and store it into a different variable same for 6 and 2 so how can I do this in **C-language** as I don't think we can use LEFT,MID and Right functions in c language

Comment: Do I have to do this via loop and if so then how im a bit confused

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Please clarify if you are using C or C++; they are very different languages.  Also, the [tag:dev-c++] tag is specifically for the obsolete Dev-C++ IDE; most likely you just want the [tag:c] or [tag:c++] tag as appropriate.  And please break your question into complete sentences using standard punctuation and grammar, and don't make the whole thing bold.

Comment: Also clarify if `num` is an integer, string, double, etc.  If you can post sample code it would help to make your question more clear.

Comment: The easiest way would be to input into a string. There, you have each digit (probably in ASCII format) in each element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through the number and store each digit in an array and on every iteration you can divide by 10 and store the number mod 10 in an index in the array

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

> how can I do this in C-language as I don't think we can use LEFT,MID
> and Right functions in c language

You can use any functions you wish - simply some are not available in the standard library and you have to write them yourself.

```
int left(int num)
{
    while(num / 10) num /= 10;
    return abs(num);
}

int right(int num)
{
    return abs(num % 10);
}

int main(void)
{
    int num = 1562;
    int leftVal = left(num);
    int rightVal = right(num);

    printf("left = %d right = %d\n", leftVal, rightVal);
}
```